# Real-time developer notifications for auto renewal subscription

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, publish-subscribe, google-play-console

I have attach 2 screenshot while facing error in real time notification for subscription configration, Please guide me if I am dong any think wrong in configration or else.[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6W1F.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l2lF.png)

Answer (score 0):

i'm also facing same issue, even though i am able to publish message from same topic in google developer console and i am receiving this message on my server.
[image from google developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZo6b.png)

i was facing same issue, but it's resolved now
try adding this  ***google-play-developer-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com*** existing service account created by google developer console as ***Pub/Sub Publisher***